# How to find out count of unique values for each column of a table

Tags: mysql, count

I want to get a count of unique values for every column in the table below. The output should have 1 row for each unique value and the same number of columns as the starting table, each of which has a count of that unique value:

table Name :- mytable

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| car     | train   | plane   | tempo   | laptop  |
| bike    | pen     | car     | Null    | pencil  |
| tempo   | book    | car     | laptop  | book    |
| Null    | bike    | tempo   | book    | pen     |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Expected output:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|         | column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| car     |    1    |    0    |    2    |    0    |    0    |
| bike    |    1    |    1    |    0    |    0    |    0    |
| tempo   |    1    |    0    |    1    |    1    |    0    |
| train   |    0    |    1    |    0    |    0    |    0    |
| pen     |    0    |    1    |    0    |    0    |    1    |
| book    |    0    |    1    |    0    |    1    |    1    |
| plane   |    0    |    0    |    1    |    0    |    0    |
| laptop  |    0    |    0    |    0    |    1    |    1    |
| pencil  |    0    |    0    |    0    |    0    |    1    |
| (null)  |    1    |    0    |    0    |    1    |    0    |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: please elaborate on output what you seek.

Comment: i had table of value's.. so first i want to find unique values from all column. Then using that values i want count of every value..  Example :- car is distinct value in table then count of 'car' is 1 in column 1 , 0 in column 2 etc...

Comment: which values do you consider unique in your sample table? pencil?

Comment: distinct value in mysql like car , train , plane , tempo , laptop , bike , pen, pencil , book etc

Comment: unique is not distinct. a unique value has a count of 1, otherwise its not unique. Distinct values can be considered as "groups of equal values"

Comment: Can you put in your question the expected output for your data sample above.

Comment: expected output :-                                                                                                               Distinct value     column1  column2  column3  column4  column 5                           Bike                    1              1             0             0             0                             car                      1               0             2            0             0

Comment: I want I want I want - did you try something on your own already?

Comment: @user3074158: please see answer below, I guess, this is what you are looking for..

Answer (score 1):

I hope, this is what you are finally look for.
all the best :)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8067/91)

**MySQL 5.5 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
  column_1 VARCHAR (20),
  column_2 VARCHAR (20),
  column_3 VARCHAR (20),
  column_4 VARCHAR (20),
  column_5 VARCHAR (20));

 insert into table_name values
('car','train','plane','tempo','laptop'); 
 insert into table_name values
('bike','pen','car',Null,'pencil'); 
 insert into table_name values
('tempo','book','car','laptop','book'); 
 insert into table_name values
(Null,'bike','tempo','book','pen');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
     valuex,
     SUM(IFNULL(ELT(FIELD(Columnx, 'Column_1'), 1), 0)) as Column_1,
     SUM(IFNULL(ELT(FIELD(Columnx, 'Column_2'), 1), 0)) as Column_2,
     SUM(IFNULL(ELT(FIELD(Columnx, 'Column_3'), 1), 0)) as Column_3,
     SUM(IFNULL(ELT(FIELD(Columnx, 'Column_4'), 1), 0)) as Column_4,
     SUM(IFNULL(ELT(FIELD(Columnx, 'Column_5'), 1), 0)) as Column_5
FROM (
  SELECT column_1 AS valuex, "Column_1" AS Columnx
  FROM table_name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT column_2 AS valuex, "Column_2" AS Columnx
  FROM table_name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT column_3 AS valuex, "Column_3" AS Columnx
  FROM table_name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT column_4 AS valuex, "Column_4" AS Columnx
  FROM table_name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT column_5 AS valuex, "Column_5" AS Columnx
  FROM table_name
) s
group by valuex
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8067/91/0)**:

```
|--------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
| valuex | Column_1 | Column_2 | Column_3 | Column_4 | Column_5 |
|--------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
| (null) |        1 |        0 |        0 |        1 |        0 |
|   bike |        1 |        1 |        0 |        0 |        0 |
|   book |        0 |        1 |        0 |        1 |        1 |
|    car |        1 |        0 |        2 |        0 |        0 |
| laptop |        0 |        0 |        0 |        1 |        1 |
|    pen |        0 |        1 |        0 |        0 |        1 |
| pencil |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        1 |
|  plane |        0 |        0 |        1 |        0 |        0 |
|  tempo |        1 |        0 |        1 |        1 |        0 |
|  train |        0 |        1 |        0 |        0 |        0 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table doesn't look normalized, so I think you should use a better structure, but without any context I cannot suggest you how to improve it. To solve your problem you could use some UNION ALL queries, and then a GROUP BY

```
SELECT value, column, COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT column1 AS value, "Column1" AS Column
  FROM mytable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT column2 AS value, "Column2" AS Column
  FROM mytable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT column3 AS value, "Column3" AS Column
  FROM mytable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT column4 AS value, "Column4" AS Column
  FROM mytable
) s
GROUP BY value, column
ORDER BY value, column
```

if you want to have all values in columns, then you can use this:

```
SELECT
  value,
  MAX(CASE WHEN column='Column1' THEN cnt END AS cnt_1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN column='Column2' THEN cnt END AS cnt_2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN column='Column3' THEN cnt END AS cnt_3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN column='Column4' THEN cnt END AS cnt_4
FROM (
  SELECT value, column, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM (
    SELECT column1 AS value, "Column1" AS Column
    FROM mytable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT column2 AS value, "Column2" AS Column
    FROM mytable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT column3 AS value, "Column3" AS Column
    FROM mytable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT column4 AS value, "Column4" AS Column
    FROM mytable
  ) AS s
  GROUP BY value, column
  ORDER BY value, column
) AS s
GROUP BY value
```

Comment: @user3074158 please have a look at my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Given the table above and assumed, you want to find the distinct values of `column1`, here's a starting point:

```
SELECT column1, count(column1) FROM myTable GROUP BY column1
```

sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1f3c7/1/0)

All columns together with a union:

```
SELECT col, count(col) FROM (
  SELECT column1 as col FROM myTable  UNION ALL
  SELECT column2 as col FROM myTable  UNION ALL
  SELECT column3 as col FROM myTable  UNION ALL
  SELECT column4 as col FROM myTable  UNION ALL
  SELECT column5 as col FROM myTable  
) as x GROUP BY x.col
```

New [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1f3c7/7/0)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8067/6)

**MySQL 5.5 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
  column_1 VARCHAR (20),
  column_2 VARCHAR (20),
  column_3 VARCHAR (20),
  column_4 VARCHAR (20),
  column_5 VARCHAR (20));

 insert into table_name values
('car','train','plane','tempo','laptop'); 
 insert into table_name values
('bike','pen','car',Null,'pencil'); 
 insert into table_name values
('tempo','book','car','laptop','book'); 
 insert into table_name values
(Null,'bike','tempo','book','pen');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select col, Count(*) from ( 
select distinct column_1 as col from table_name
union all
select distinct column_2 as col from table_name
union all
select distinct column_3 as col from table_name
union all
select distinct column_4 as col from table_name
union all
select distinct column_5 as col from table_name) as newTable
group by col
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8067/6/0)**:

```
|    col | Count(*) |
|--------|----------|
| (null) |        2 |
|   bike |        2 |
|   book |        3 |
|    car |        2 |
| laptop |        2 |
|    pen |        2 |
| pencil |        1 |
|  plane |        1 |
|  tempo |        3 |
|  train |        1 |
```

Comment: i want count in all five column not in single Count(*)

Comment: expected out in following format :-                                                                                                             distinct value   (count in) column1    (count in) column2   (count in) (count in)column3   (count in)column4   (count in)column5

Answer (score 0):

As per @fthiella's logic here is the answer, and I am sure this is what you really wanted :)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8067/9)

**MySQL 5.5 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
  column_1 VARCHAR (20),
  column_2 VARCHAR (20),
  column_3 VARCHAR (20),
  column_4 VARCHAR (20),
  column_5 VARCHAR (20));

 insert into table_name values
('car','train','plane','tempo','laptop'); 
 insert into table_name values
('bike','pen','car',Null,'pencil'); 
 insert into table_name values
('tempo','book','car','laptop','book'); 
 insert into table_name values
(Null,'bike','tempo','book','pen');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT valueX, columnX, COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT column_1 AS valuex, "Column_1" AS Columnx
  FROM table_name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT column_2 AS valuex, "Column_2" AS Columnx
  FROM table_name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT column_3 AS valuex, "Column_3" AS Columnx
  FROM table_name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT column_4 AS valuex, "Column_4" AS Columnx
  FROM table_name
) s
GROUP BY valuex, columnX
ORDER BY valuex, columnX
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8067/9/0)**:

```
| valuex |  Columnx | COUNT(*) |
|--------|----------|----------|
| (null) | Column_1 |        1 |
| (null) | Column_4 |        1 |
|   bike | Column_1 |        1 |
|   bike | Column_2 |        1 |
|   book | Column_2 |        1 |
|   book | Column_4 |        1 |
|    car | Column_1 |        1 |
|    car | Column_3 |        2 |
| laptop | Column_4 |        1 |
|    pen | Column_2 |        1 |
|  plane | Column_3 |        1 |
|  tempo | Column_1 |        1 |
|  tempo | Column_3 |        1 |
|  tempo | Column_4 |        1 |
|  train | Column_2 |        1 |
```

Comment: i want 6 column in output..can u please help me out